# prove that the order of H is greater than 1 (it implies that H≠{e})

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

Let {G,∗} be a group with identity e and let a∈G be a fixed element in G with a≠e.  Define H={x|x∈G and x∗a=a∗x}

(1)prove that the order of H is greater than 1 (it implies that H≠{e})

Comment: Your edits are largely an improvement to the Question, but I have a couple of criticisms to offer.  Before we can talk about the order of $H$ (order here means *size* of a group) we have to prove that $H$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$.  Also the added tag [tag:order-theory] is not pertinent (there order has the sense of a *partial order*).